# howler js volume slider in loop doesn't work after 1st play

Tags: javascript, loops, audio

I'm using howler.js for a random audio player which seems great and I'm sure will do what i want eventually when i learn everything i need to ! I have it working and a volume slider also ( thanks to another post on here) however.... the volume slider seems to only work on first play . When it picks the next file it doesn't. Is this something to do with scope or is it the fact that I'm triggering the next loop within the function using 'on end;  ( i think)

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"              "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
  <title></title>
   </head>
  <body>
  <script src="howler.core.js"></script>
  <script>

  function createHowl() {
   var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 14) + 1);
   return new Howl({
    src:      ['audio/' + number + '.wav'],
    autoplay: false,
    loop:     false,
    volume:   1.0,
    onend:    function() {createHowl().play()}
    });
    }

      function showValue(newValue) {
      document.getElementById('range').innerHTML=newValue;
      howl.volume(newValue);
      }

      var howl = createHowl();
      howl.play();

       </script>
       <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.01"   onchange="showValue(this.value)" oninput="showValue(this.value)"/>
        <span id="range">0</span>   </body>
         </html>
```

it all seems to work other than the volume slider. I can't work it out but reckon its to do with the on end. But then i can't get it to loop without it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're creating a new howl object in the onend. You need to ensure that the howl variable always points to the latest playing sound.

```
var currentHowl = null

function createHowl() {
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 14) + 1);
  currentHowl = new Howl({
    src:      ['audio/' + number + '.wav'],
    autoplay: false,
    loop:     false,
    volume:   1.0,
    onend:    function() {createHowl().play()}
  });

  return currentHowl
}

function showValue(newValue) {
  document.getElementById('range').innerHTML=newValue;
  currentHowl.volume(newValue);
}

var howl = createHowl();
howl.play();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This still doesnt seem to work however. The player loops fine and the slider value updates but volume stays set where is